# How to create a user input on Pygame?

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I am trying to create a user interface for a sudoku solver made with python. So far I can display a 9x9 grid, and I want the user to be able to click on a block, enter a number, and do this for all starting numbers in the grid. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Walid, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share your code so far, and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs an event loop, where it waits for mouse clicks.  When a mouse click is received, the code needs to determine which of the 81 sub-rectangles was clicked in.

With the window dimensions, and grid size stored in variables:

```
# Window stuff
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 600
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
GRID_SIZE     = 9
GRID_WIDTH_X  = WINDOW_WIDTH  // GRID_SIZE
GRID_HEIGHT_Y = WINDOW_HEIGHT // GRID_SIZE
```

When the mouse-click event is received, simply dividing the co-ordinate by the matching grid-size will give the cell-index where it was clicked. X for X-width, and Y for Y-height.  Obviously this gives a 0-based offset, numbering the cells [0,0] to [8,8].

```
    elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
        # Where was the click on the screen?
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        cell_x = mouse_x // GRID_WIDTH_X
        cell_y = mouse_y // GRID_HEIGHT_Y
        print( "Click in cell [%d,%d]" % ( cell_x, cell_y ) )
```

This location can then be edited, updated, etc.

Full source:

```
import pygame

# Window stuff
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 600
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
GRID_SIZE     = 9
GRID_WIDTH_X  = WINDOW_WIDTH  // GRID_SIZE
GRID_HEIGHT_Y = WINDOW_HEIGHT // GRID_SIZE

BACKGROUND_COLOUR = ( 200, 200, 200 )
GRID_COLOUR       = ( 200,  10,  10 )

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )
pygame.display.set_caption( "Suduko Solver Question" )

clock   = pygame.time.Clock()
exiting = False
# Main Loop
while not exiting:

    # Handle User Input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            exiting = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
            # Where was the click on the screen?
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            cell_x = mouse_x // GRID_WIDTH_X
            cell_y = mouse_y // GRID_HEIGHT_Y
            print( "Click in cell [%d,%d]" % ( cell_x, cell_y ) )


    # Draw the screen
    window.fill( BACKGROUND_COLOUR )
    for i in range( GRID_SIZE ):
        x_coord = i * GRID_WIDTH_X
        y_coord = i * GRID_HEIGHT_Y
        pygame.draw.line( window, GRID_COLOUR, ( x_coord, 0 ), ( x_coord, WINDOW_WIDTH-1 ) )
        pygame.draw.line( window, GRID_COLOUR, ( 0, y_coord ), ( WINDOW_WIDTH-1, y_coord ) )

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)  # limit FPS

pygame.quit()
```